# Reverse flatten nested arrays with jq

Tags: json, jq

Suppose I have the following nested data structure

```
cat nested.json
[
    {
        "a": "a",
        "b": [
            {"c": "c"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "a": "a",
        "b": [
            {"c": "c"}
        ]
    }
]
```

I can flatten it like this

```
cat nested.json | jq '
  [. as $in | reduce paths(scalars) as $path ({};
    . + { ($path | map(tostring) | join(".")): $in | getpath($path) }
  )]
' > flat.json

cat flat.json
[
  {
    "0.a": "a",
    "0.b.0.c": "c",
    "1.a": "a",
    "1.b.0.c": "c"
  }
]
```

To reverse the flatten operation with `jq` I tried this

```
cat flat.json | jq '
  .[0] | reduce to_entries[] as $kv ({};
    setpath($kv.key|split("."); $kv.value)
  )
'

{
  "0": {
    "a": "a",
    "b": {
      "0": {
        "c": "c"
      }
    }
  },
  "1": {
    "a": "a",
    "b": {
      "0": {
        "c": "c"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I want to convert numbers in the `setpath` param to create arrays. This doesn't quite work, but I think it's close?

```
cat flat.json  | jq '
  def makePath($s): [split(".")[] | if (test("\\d+")) then tonumber else . end];
  .[0] | reduce to_entries[] as $kv ({}; setpath(makePath($kv.key); $kv.value))
'

jq: error (at <stdin>:8): split input and separator must be strings
```

The **desired output is the same as the original data** in `nested.json`

Comment: What is the desired output? Can you update it?

Comment: Please add the desired output, your question is quite unclear.

Comment: The desired output is the same as the original data in nested.json

Comment: "The desired output is the same as the original data in nested.json" so you don't need to change anything at all? Even more unclear now..

Comment: @0stone0, It was clear from the start. `flat.json` is the input, `nested.json` is the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't it be simpler to do it this way:

Encode your input with

```
jq '[path(.. | scalars) as $path | {($path | join(".")): getpath($path)}] | add' nested.json
{
  "0.a": "a",
  "0.b.0.c": "c",
  "1.a": "a",
  "1.b.0.c": "c"
}
```

And decode it with

```
jq 'reduce to_entries[] as $item (null; setpath($item.key / "." | map(tonumber? // .); $item.value))' flat.json
[
  {
    "a": "a",
    "b": [
      {
        "c": "c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "a": "a",
    "b": [
      {
        "c": "c"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

However, if you don't care about your *special dot notation* (e.g. `"0.b.0.c"`) for the encoded keys, you can simply convert the path array into a JSON string instead, having albeit uglier virtually the same effect. Moreover, it would automatically enable the handling of input object field names that include dots (e.g. `{"a.b":3}`) or look like numbers (e.g. `{"42":"Panic!"}`).

Using JSON keys, encode your input with

```
jq '[path(.. | scalars) as $path | {($path | tojson): getpath($path)}] | add' nested.json
{
  "[0,\"a\"]": "a",
  "[0,\"b\",0,\"c\"]": "c",
  "[1,\"a\"]": "a",
  "[1,\"b\",0,\"c\"]": "c"
}
```

And decode it with

```
jq 'reduce to_entries[] as $item (null; setpath($item.key | fromjson; $item.value))' flat.json
[
  {
    "a": "a",
    "b": [
      {
        "c": "c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "a": "a",
    "b": [
      {
        "c": "c"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: The first two "simpler" filters don't work for me. I get `null`, and `jq: error (at flat.json:8): number (0) and string (".") cannot be divided`. What version of jq did you use?  I've got jq-1.6

Comment: I get your point about "handling of input object field names that include dots... or look like numbers". For my specific use case it's important to have flat-keys without special characters, and I know the nested object won't have keys with dots or that look like numbers.

Comment: I didn't want to discourage you from using your dot notation, I just wanted you to know its caveats. As for the error: Initially I had a working solution but then I was suggested to reduce `path(.. | scalars)` to `path(scalars)` for supposedly being identical, which eventually broke the code. My bad. I reverted that change, now it should work out fine. Try it here: [Encoder](https://jqplay.org/s/gzbiHi0QE5), [Decoder](https://jqplay.org/s/W67e4xvuw1)

Comment: Awesome thanks, this works! I had to change your filters slightly so the output is always an array. It makes my marshal and un-marshal logic easier elsewhere.